# Submission of form does not work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

**Problem:**

Trying to automatically generate a form and submit it without user interference.

**Complete code:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {        
            var url = 'test.php';
            var form = $('
                <form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="Datafile" value="' + <?php echo "upload/".$_SESSION['txtfile'].""; ?> + '">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="Perspective" value="' + <?php echo implode(" ", $_SESSION['dimensions']); ?> + '">' + 
                    '<input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="true">' +
                '</form>
            ');
            $('body').append(form);
            $(form).submit();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

It gives me first an error when looking at the source code that implode() parameters are wrong.

**Desired solution:**

The form should submit itself once it has been loaded.

Anyone who can spot what's wrong or why the form does not submit itself?

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['dimensions']` that `implode()` doesn't like?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load jQuery in document:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This should have been a common because it addresses only a part of the problem, rather than the entire issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery why aren't you just sending the data via post?

```
    $.post( "test.php", { name: "<?php echo "upload/".$_SESSION['txtfile']; ?>" , 
            Perspective: "<?php echo implode(" ", $_SESSION['dimensions']); ?>",
            form_submitted : "true"} );
```

Comment: Also are you sure that the sessions are actually there? Can you echo dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                function AutoSubmit(){
                    document.my_form.submit();
                }

        </script>
         </head>
        <body onLoad="AutoSubmit();">
                    <form action="test.php" name="my_form" id="my_form"  method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="Datafile" value="<?php echo "upload/".$_SESSION['txtfile']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="Perspective" value="<?php echo implode(" ", $_SESSION['dimensions']); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="true">
                    </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function()
        {        
            var url = 'test.php';
            var form =
                "<form action="+url+" method=\"post\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Datafile\" value=\"<?php echo \"upload/\".$_SESSION[\'txtfile\'].\"; ?> \"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Perspective\" value=\" <?php echo implode(\" \", $_SESSION[\'dimensions\']); ?>\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_submitted\" value=\"true\"></form>";

            $('body').append(form);
            $(form).submit();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```